# py2app: SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier in setup file

Tags: python, syntax-error, py2app

I am trying to build an executable file from my python code.
I can run the program from the console without any problems:
[Running the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPY80.png)

But when I run the py2app command, I get the following error:
[SyntaxError message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AqmS.png)

setup_mac.py contains the following code:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = [‘main.py’]
DATA_FILES = [‘client_secret.json’,’Interface.py’, ’spreadsheet.py’]

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={‘py2app’},
    setup_requires=[‘py2app’],
)
```

I don't see where to problem is, especially as I can run the program...

Answer (score 2):

You are surrounding your strings with U+2018 (LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) and U+2019 (RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK).  You need to use either `'` or `"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the underscores around the equals signs in the `setup` call.

Comment: removed them (had them in because of a YT_tutorial which had it that way), but the Error remains the same